# R markdown on OSX: pdflatex not found

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

I got the error when trying to knitr a R markdown file to pdf on OSX:

pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41
Execution halted

No TeX installation detected (TeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a recommended TeX distribution for your platform:

Windows: MiKTeX (Complete) - http://miktex.org/2.9/setup
  (NOTE: Be sure to download the Complete rather than Basic installation)

Mac OS X: TexLive 2013 (Full) - http://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome *strongly* recommended)

Following the link in the error, I downloaded mactex and installed it. However, the error persists when I tried to knitr in pdf. I can render it to html and word, as two other options available, but the pdf option gets me the error

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331343/knitting-to-pdf-in-r

Comment: can you run `pdflatex` from a terminal prompt?