# Error when Trying to use Rticles to generate example R markdown: pdflatex not found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, pdflatex, tinytex

I was trying to generate one of the example rticles outputs in pdf, and got the same error `pdflatex not found`. This was on Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first followed Yihue's troubleshooting [site](https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging), but got the same error found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259556/r-markdown-on-osx-pdflatex-not-found), [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/new-problems-producing-pdf-from-rmarkdown/5850), and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285#issuecomment-374340175) . In R on Ubuntu 20.04, I first installed tinytex using `devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')`. I then tried to do `library(tinytex)` and `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` which returned an error `Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : error in running command`. I assumed this was because I was missing something on Ubuntu 20.04. It seems that as of July 14, 2020, Ubuntu 20.04 or rticles does not ship with Texlive, which is necessary for output. I thus ran `sudo apt install texlive-full` at the command line and was able to run the example.